# Azure Data Factory: How to import a complex json object from Avro file

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, avro

I am using ADF to parse a series of Avro files.  The tricky part about this exercise is that the payload will contain a metrics array of varying sizes.  And within each metric, there will be slightly different schemas.

[image]

This is what I have so far.  I have flattened down the file so that I have this column.

[image]

So I will have an array of "payload metrics"....

[image]

..... and as you can see, there might be one or more levels of nesting at this level.

Long story short, what is the best way to proceed if I want to continue to break up this json node?  Is there a way to dynamically break out the columns in the payload?

Comment: can you add sample input output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Flatten settings, click  `+Add mapping` -> `Rule based mapping`

[image]

- Then in mapping, give the matching condition expression as `true()` and check the`Deep column traversal` checkbox.

[image]

This will dynamically flatten all the subcolumns of complex field.

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten#rule-based-mapping